# How to plot a matrix in scatterplot python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a matrix A:

```
    A = np.matrix(np.random.rand(4,2))


    matrix([[ 0.01124212,  0.45879116],
            [ 0.10993219,  0.00142847],
            [ 0.34650295,  0.98693131],
            [ 0.20417694,  0.81177707]])
```

Is there an easy way to use matplotlib (or similar libary) to show a scatterplot in 2-d? When I use `plt.plot(A)` it shows as a line graph.

Comment: The linked answer seems long when you can just do this: `plt.scatter(*A.T)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define rows in your numpy array as `x, y` pairs:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
A = np.matrix(np.random.rand(4,2))

#scatter plot x - column 0, y - column 1, shown with marker o
plt.plot(A[:, 0], A[:, 1], 'o', label = 'data')
#create legend in case you have more than one series
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```